# Load .ckpt files from CivitAi into pytorch for inference

Tags: pytorch, dynamic-image-generation, stable-diffusion

I've been researching all over for a tutorial/guide to load a civitAI model (https://civitai.com/models/4823/deliberate) into pytorch and then use it for Inference.

Most research leads to the following:

1. Create your base model (which should have the same model Architecture as the model from where the checkpoint was save).
2. Then loading the checkpoint using torch.load()
3. torch.load_state_dict(loaded_checkpoint)

However, the models on civitai only have the ckpt file and nothing more. So cannot do step 1.
I do know it's possible, because the GUI version AUTOMATIC1111 is able to do it.

PS. I do know that the same deliberate model is available on huggingface.co and can be downloaded like standard stable diffusion models, but i'm interested in working with the ckpt file alone and do it the way AUTO1111 does it.

```
model_id = "stabilityai/stable-diffusion-2-1"
model = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(model_id, torch_dtype=torch.float16)
model.scheduler = DPMSolverMultistepScheduler.from_config(pipe.scheduler.config)

# Load the Checkpoint File
ckpt_path = '/Users/XXXX/XXXX/model.ckpt'
checkpoint = torch.load(ckpt_path, map_location="cpu")
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
model.eval()

image = model(prompt='xxxxxx')
```

Answer (score 1):

The requirement is that you install [`diffusers`](https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/en/index) and [`peft`](https://github.com/huggingface/peft) (`pip install peft diffusers`).

#### Loading LoRA `.safetensors`

You can use **Hugging Face** stable diffusion [`load_lora_weight`](https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/main/en/api/loaders#diffusers.loaders.StableDiffusionXLLoraLoaderMixin.load_lora_weights) method.

For this demo, I am downloading this LoRA weight: [*Styles for Pony Diffusion V6 XL*](https://civitai.com/models/264290/styles-for-pony-diffusion-v6-xl-not-artists-styles?modelVersionId=396157).

```
!wget https://civitai.com/api/download/models/396157?type=Model&format=SafeTensor
!mv "396157?type=Model" "lora.safetensors"
```

Load the pipeline (be careful to load the same version as the one the LoRA was performed on! Here XL-1.0), then load the LoRA weighs:

```
import torch
from diffusers import DiffusionPipeline


pipeline = DiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(
    "stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0", torch_dtype=torch.float16
).to("cuda")

pipeline.load_lora_weights("lora.safetensors")
image, *_ = pipeline(text).images
image.save("output.png")
```

| example output |
| --- |
| [image] |

---

#### Loading checkpoint `.safetensors`

If you are looking to load checkpoint instead but have access to a `.safetensors` then you can't rely on [`from_pretrained`](https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/v0.27.1/en/api/pipelines/overview#diffusers.DiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained). According to the documentation [*"Load safetensors"*](https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/en/using-diffusers/using_safetensors), you need to rely on [`from_single_file`](https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/v0.27.1/en/api/pipelines/stable_diffusion/img2img#diffusers.StableDiffusionImg2ImgPipeline.from_single_file) to initialize and load the pipeline:

Here I am downloading the checkpoint from: [*Vapor - A Futuristic Retro Experience*](https://civitai.com/models/141930/vapor-a-futuristic-retro-experience).

The following code was tested on Google collab:

```
!wget https://civitai.com/api/download/models/157346
!mv "157346" "checkpoint.safetensors"
```

Then you can load the checkpoint with a single line:

```
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline

pipeline = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_single_file("checkpoint.safetensors")

image, *_ = pipeline(text).images
image.save("output.png")
```

| example output |
| --- |
| [image] |